# unable to load "gcs.csv" file in gdal

Tags: python, gdal

This question might be repeat but I did not get answer.
I have write flowing code in python ide .

```
out_srs = osr.SpatialReference()

   **self.out_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)**
```

It run fine but when i run it from application it cause an error as follows

Note - Error in line enclosed in 2 stars **-----**

```
"Unable to load EPSG support gcs.csv file check setting GDAL_DATA environment variable which point to gdal library contains EPSG.csv file"
```

I have done it but i still get this error. but this code run separately but not in application. This code is from gdal2tile module of gdal. i am using python 2.7.6 and gdal 1.10.0 I am unable to sort out what is the problem and where it is. Please suggest how to solve this.

Comment: How does it know that `geodetic` refers back to `out_srs` in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GDAL needs an environment variable named `GDAL_DATA` that points to [a directory with various data files](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/data), including `gcs.csv`. [Learn more about it **here**](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQInstallationAndBuilding#WhatisGDAL_DATAenvironmentvariable).

To check if `GDAL_DATA` is set, and contains `gcs.csv`, and if this is readable, use the following snippets to check the application. This should be near the code that raises the error.

```
import os
import stat
gdal_data = os.environ['GDAL_DATA']
print('is dir: ' + str(os.path.isdir(gdal_data)))
gcs_csv = os.path.join(gdal_data, 'gcs.csv')
print('is file: ' + str(os.path.isfile(gcs_csv)))
st = os.stat(gcs_csv)
print('is readable: ' + str(bool(st.st_mode & stat.S_IRGRP)))
```

---

## Anaconda / Miniconda users

The correct way to use either Anaconda or Miniconda is to [activate an environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) where GDAL is installed. For example, activate the base environment for Anaconda from Windows cmd.exe:

```
call %LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat base
```

Activating an environment triggers environment variables such as GDAL_DATA (and others) to be set, and often changes the command prompt prefix showing the environment name. These environment variables are unset/restored when the environment is deactivated.

```
conda deactivate
```

Comment: After running this from appliction it return following output GDAL_DATA:C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data;

Comment: How about the updated checks? You don't need to show the output, just if they all say `True` or not.

Comment: out put of above code is follows                                     is dir false is file false                                    C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-data;\\gcs.csv     the smicolon in path is the problem why this come i dont understand

Comment: In IDLE, where you don't see the original error, do you see all `True` for the checks to see gcs.csv?

Comment: one false and rest r true

Comment: Setting GDAL_DATA to the correct path does not work for me (Python 3.4 within Anaconda) although os.path.isfile(os.environ['GDAL_DATA']) and bool(os.stat(os.environ['GDAL_DATA']).st_mode & stat.S_IRGRP) both return True. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by taking the following steps to set the GDAL_DATA variable in windows.

1. Find the folder where gdal data is stored

   ```
   \Anaconda2\envs\gdaltest\Library\share\gdal
   ```
2. open windows command prompt and run following command with the location of your gdal data folder.

   ```
   set GDAL_DATA=....\....\Library\share\gdal
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me on MacOS Catalina (10.15.5) while playing with PyQGIS (QGIS 3.12). Just searched on Mac finder for `gcs.csv` which returned multiple results:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_4/share/gdal/gcs.csv

/Library/Frameworks/UnixImageIO.framework/Versions/F/Resources/epsg_csv/gcs.csv

/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.2/Resources/gdal/gcs.csv
```

I stick with `GDAL.Framework` and just added this environment variable into my script:

```
import os

os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.2/Resources/gdal/'
```

Script is not complaining anymore.