# Geo Django GDAL: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv

Tags: django, gdal, geodjango, ogr, osgeo

I recently did a clean window installed. I installed OSGeo4W via: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/
I installed GDAL by downloading the pip wheel **GDAL-2.3.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl**
I also configured my django **settings.py** to:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    import sys

    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
    GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = sys.path[6] + r'\osgeo\gdal203.dll'
```

This configuration worked on my previous machine but when trying to edit a django model with a Point field I would get this error:

```
GDAL_ERROR 4: b'Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.'
Error transforming geometry from srid '4326' to srid '3857' (OGR failure.)
GDAL_ERROR 4: b'Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.'
Internal Server Error: /admin/event/event/31/change/
```

I followed the same configuration as my previous setup. Same machine but new OS so I'm a bit stomped.
How can I configure the GDAL_DATA env variable? 
I tried the suggestion:

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/52597276/9469766**

setting GDAL:

```
GDAL_DATA= OSGEO4W + r'\share\gdal'
```

and

```
GDAL_DATA= OSGEO4W + r'\share\epsg_csv'
```

but both still produced the same exception.

Comment: What's the content of the directory you're pointing to? Eg, `os.listdir(os.environ['GDAL_DATA'])`, does it contain `gcs.csv`?

Comment: `epsg_csv` contains the `gcs.csv` file along with 33 other files.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue as well. I ended up fixing it by running the web gis express install for OSGeo4W which adds the folder epsg_csv which should allow you to use:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\epsg_csv"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be some one have better solution but after applying number of fix I am able to find the only solution which worked for me that WSL and Remote debug in Pycharm. I have made a public gist you may try the settings.
[GeoDjango Configurations](https://gist.github.com/abdulrehmanch/0cf4a9f52cbeb626b85c3f9629e218e4)